# adding the same thing in tablerow causes fc

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

i am doing exactly what this page says: http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/Dynamically_adding_rows_to_TableLayout

main code:

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

```
      /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
      TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTableLayout);
           /* Create a new row to be added. */
           TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
           tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
                Button b = new Button(this);
                b.setText("Dynamic Button");
                b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                /* Add Button to row. */
                tr.addView(b);
      /* Add row to TableLayout. */
      tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); <code>
```

xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
     <TableRow
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <Button android:text="Static Button"/>
     </TableRow>
</TableLayout>`

but when i duplicate the line 
tr.addView(b);

it gives me fc.
Any idea where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are adding the same button. Try:

```
            .....
            /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
            Button b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("Dynamic Button");
            b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            /* Add Button to row. */
            tr.addView(b);

            b = new Button(this);
            b.setText("Another Dynamic Button");
            b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            /* Add Button to row. */
            tr.addView(b);   

            ......
```

Comment: you can add different buttons but not the same.